# force hasmany with same ids (or ids ember doesn't know about)

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I want ember to list all foo's on `{{#each foo}}` even though the id's are the same.

This is my model.

```
App.Item = DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr("string"),
  foo: DS.hasMany("foo", {async: true})
});

App.Foo = DS.Model.extend({
  bar: DS.attr("string")
});
```

Let's say that foo is `foo: [1]` and the json response for that is:

```
{
  "foos": [{
    "id": 1,
    "bar": "But is it _lightweight_ omakase?"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "bar": "I for one welcome our new omakase overlords"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "bar": "Put me on the fast track to a delicious dinner"
  }]
}
```

Ember only lists the last object instead of everyone. I know that ember wants different ids, but is there a way to force ember to list all objects with same ids?

I'm using ember data and this is a read-only app.

**EDIT**

With different ids on the objects it still doesn't work. Foo can still only have 1: `foo:[1]` though. So that's the problem.

My problem is that I can't list all the id's on foo. So I need a way to get ember to show whatever comes back from the request whether it knows about the ids or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Have you considered switching to a URL based model... –  GJK

This is exactly what I was after. I didn't notice the [findHasMany](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTAdapter.html#method_findHasMany) method in my search. More info [here](http://jsonapi.org/format/#document-structure-resource-relationships).

Instead of `foo: [1]` use `links: { foo: "http://example.org/foo/1" }` And ember will list the foos without having to list all the ids on foo.

Answer (score 0):

> I know that ember wants different ids, but is there a way to force ember to list all objects with same ids?

The short answer is no. IDs are identifiers, specifically *unique* identifiers with Ember Data. You can't have two objects with the same type and ID. Give them different IDs and everything will work fine.

Comment: okay. I gave them different ids but it doesn't work. foo is still `foo: [1]` though. Can I get ember to list the new objects with unique ids even though there's still only one in foo?

Comment: `My problem is that I can't list all the id's on foo.` That is probably your problem. Have you considered switching to a URL based model like the one mentioned [here](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTAdapter.html#method_findHasMany)? (More info [here](http://jsonapi.org/format/#document-structure-resource-relationships).)

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I wanted. I used it in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'd advise taking real care with plurality, it'll keep things much clearer.

I don't really understand what you're looking to do here, but I'd suggest it might be one of these two things.

a) Each "item" has many "foos". In which case I'd change slightly:

```
App.Item = DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr("string"),
  foos: DS.hasMany("foo", {async: true})
});

App.Foo = DS.Model.extend({
  bar: DS.attr("string")
  item: DS.belongsTo('item', {async: true})
});
```

And get each "foo" from the server.

```
{
  "foos": [{
    "id": 1,
    "bar": "But is it _lightweight_ omakase?"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "bar": "I for one welcome our new omakase overlords"
  }...
```

You can then display each "foo"'s "bar" with:

```
{{#each item in model}}
    {{item.title}}
    {{#each foo in item.foos}}
        {{foo.bar}}
```

b) If each "item" has just one "foo" you'll still need different ids unless you just keep the one and update it. Maybe keep a separate archive table if its important? Otherwise maybe maintain an extra attribute in your "foo" model along the line of "isCurrent" or "isValid". I'll admit I have no idea what best practice is here.